# How do I count cell values from a binding source on a combobox selected index change event?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am trying to count the number of vacation hours/days someone has taken. I want to filter on a datagridview by name from a combobox. I was able to do this using a datatable but when I went to a combobox selectedindex change event I went to a binding source and there is no datatable feature to assist.

Here is my code thus far using a datatable to get the cell value count in a datagridview

```
con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from VacReq where Employee_Name = '" + Globals.FirstLast + "' ", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        con.Close();

        int sumPto = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("SUM(Pto)", string.Empty));
        int sumFloat = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("SUM(Float)", string.Empty));
        txtUsedPto.Text = Convert.ToString(sumPto);
        txtUsedFloat.Text = Convert.ToString(sumFloat);
```

Here is where I am stuck using the combobox selectedindex change event using a binding source.

```
 private void CmbUserName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
        bs.Filter = dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + cmbUserName.Text + "%'";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

[image]

[image]

I just want to select a user name in the combobox which filters by that user name in the datagridview and then count the total number of days/hours they have taken this year.

[image: Ige]
I get this error for the above picture.
[image]
However, if I run the code like this it works but if I go to the combobox and change the user I get the same error above. I added a refresh grid button and that refreshes the grid to show all users again but the minute I select another user I get the same error "Unable to cast object of type".

Comment: What values are in the combo box? What values are in the `_ID` column in the grid? In the second code snippet… why is the code filtering the data based on “Vacation_Start”? It is unclear what values are in the combo box but it appears the code is trying to “filter” whatever is in the combo box with “Vacation_Start” which looks like a date? This is confusing considering that you state that you want to “filter” by user. Can you clarify any of this?

Comment: The combobox only displays names that match the names in the column you can't see for obvious reasons. _ID is employee_ID, there is no filter on ascending or descending on the grid. I just want to select a name from the commobox and then the grid filters by that name only.

Comment: You have articulated “what” you want to do… however, it is not clear what the problem/issue is. We have to assume many things that you are not providing and the only thing I can see that would cause the code to not work is what I said in my first comment… if you want to filter by “_ID”… then why is the filter using the `Vacation_Start` column? From what I can see it should be `Columns[0].HeaderText`. Also, it appears that you may be using the `BindingSource` to filter the data source and this will work, however, you can also filter a `DataTable`.

Comment: Lastly, it is unclear what values “_ID” may contain… are they `numeric` values or `string` values… point being you will not be able to use “LIKE” with numeric values.

Comment: I do not think you are grasping what I am saying. Let me make this clear. The _ID is an employee ID column which is called Employee_ID I have the data hidden (scrolled to where you cannot see the data) that column is actually column[2] before that is PII info that I did not want to release. Added the datagrid with blank data for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume the filtering is working as expected and the problem is you do not know how to sum the total days values when the grid is filtered. The only code I see that attempts to “sum” the values is when the code gets the data from the DB…

```
int sumPto = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("SUM(Pto)", string.Empty));
int sumFloat = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("SUM(Float)", string.Empty));
```

This obviously is going to sum ALL the values in the column. You state that …

> I just want to select a user name in the combobox which filters by
> that user name in the datagridview and then count the total number of
> days/hours they have taken this year.

A quick glance at the docs for the `Compute` method … [DataTable.Compute(String, String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.compute?view=net-6.0) … would reveal that the second parameter is the “filter” expression. Therefore it would appear that you could use the same “filter” that the `BindingSource` uses to filter by the selected user in the combo box. Something like…

```
bs.Filter = dataGridView1.Columns["_ID"].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + CmbUserName.Text + "%'";
textBox1.Text = Convert.ToInt32(((DataTable)bs.DataSource).Compute("SUM(Total_Days)", bs.Filter)).ToString();
```

It is unknown “where” to want to display this total to the user. I used a simple `TextBox` to display the total. This code could be used in the combo boxes `SelectedIndexChanged` event to update the filtered user for the grid in addition to updating the text box with the current user’s total.

This event may look something like…

```
private void CmbUserName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)dataGridView1.DataSource;
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CmbUserName.Text)) {
    bs.Filter = dataGridView1.Columns["_ID"].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + CmbUserName.Text + "%'";
    textBox1.Text = Convert.ToInt32(((DataTable)bs.DataSource).Compute("SUM(Total_Days)", bs.Filter)).ToString();
  }
  else {
    bs.Filter = "";
    textBox1.Text = "";
  }
}
```

You should note that the code is NOT re-setting the grids data source nor the binding sources data source. You should only have to set them ONCE. So in the forms load event you may have some code that looks like…

```
DataTable BindingSourceDT = GetDataFromDB();
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = BindingSourceDT;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

Comment: I know how to sum the cells, I cannot get the filter to work. I just want to select Joe Blow from the combobox and the datagridview filters by Joe Blow. I will certainly try to add the combobox to the filter like you displayed. Thank you so much.

Comment: Well… in my code the filter works as expected. My “_ID” values are simple strings. Each value in the combo box is a non-duplicated “_ID.” Select an “_ID” in the combo box and the grid filters as expected. If you are not able to filter the data as I have in my answer… then you must be doing something else. I suggest you show how you are adding items to the combo box. You continue to make things more difficult for us to help to you.

Comment: I updated my question. Getting a unable to cast object of type.

Comment: @Anthony Mullins … The error you posted is clear… The grid’s `DataSource` is a `DataTable` and your code is trying to “cast” the `DataTable` to a `BindingSource` which obviously will not work. Make the grids `DataSource` a `BindingSource` … look at my answers last code snippet. This code should probably be in the forms load event.